# How to set FileDialog's folder from a UNC path in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, unc, qt5.6

I want to store the last used folder in a file dialog in qml (using Qt version 5.6). The way I do it is through QSettings that has a url property `lastUsedFolder` as such:

```
/////////////
/// myApp.qml
/////////////

import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0

Settings {
    id: settings
    property url lastUsedFolder;
}

FileDialog {
    id: openDialog
    onVisibleChanged:
    {
        if(visible && myApp.doesFolderStillExist(settings.lastUsedFolder))
        {
            console.log("setting folder of dialog")
            folder = settings.lastUsedFolder
            console.log(folder)
        }
    }
    onAccepted:
    {
        console.log("saving folder: " + folder)
        settings.lastUsedFolder = folder;
    }
}

/////////////
/// myApp.cpp
/////////////
bool myApp::doesFolderStillExist(QUrl folderUrl)
{
    QFileInfo folder(folderUrl.toLocalFile());
    if (folder.exists())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

This works well enough when working with local files, but does not when using files on remote computers addressed by a UNC-format path such as `\\myRemotePC.somewhere.com\myData\`.

If I navigate to this address and accept the dialog, the folder is stored thanks to the onAccepted method and the console prints `saving folder: file://myRemotePC.somewhere.com/myData`. Then when I open the dialog again, the onVisibleChanged triggers. The `doesFolderStillExists` method sees the folder - the QUrl.toLocalFile seems to work - and also the stored path in `settings.lastUsedFolder` is still the same that was stored. But then the app crashes on the line that assigns to the `folder` property with the following error (Windows 7; the last console print is just the "setting folder of dialog"):

`QWindowsNativeFileDialogBase::shellItem: SHCreateItemFromParsingName(file:///myRemotePC.somewhere.com/myData) failed ()`

In other words, it crashes when I try to set the folder property of the dialog using the exact same value I read from it before...and that confuses me.

Not sure if it matters, but one strange thing I noticed is that the error message has three forward slashes after the `file:`, while the path that I am setting as the folder has only two. I tried to modify the path in various ways:

- if the `file:` is omitted entirely, the dialog opens in the default location, probably failing to parse the address in a meaningful way - which is kind of expected
- no matter how many forward slashes I add or remove after the `file:`, the same error message appears, always with three slashes in the shown path

I would appreciate any advice that would lead me to being able to store and re-use the last used folder in a FileDialog in a way that is usable for both "local" and UNC paths, even if it was done in a different way than we are currently using.

Answer (score 3):

It seem to be an error from Qt.
QFileDialog try to "correct" your URI in a bad way, cause if you convert an UNC path like "\myRemotePC.somewhere.com\myData\" into an URI it will give you  "file://myRemotePC.somewhere.com/myData", this part is correct, but from QFileDialog point of view, you try to get a local folder.

I try to feed the QFileDialog with raw string or url but QFileDialog persist to convert the path.

If you need one workaround, call QFileDialog from C++, it work with string path like UNC path.

Another workaround, connect your external folder as network drive.

Sorry for my poor English ^^

If someone want a fast try.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0

Window {
Component.onCompleted: {
    openDialog.open();
}

FileDialog {
    id: openDialog
    selectFolder: true
    Component.onCompleted:  folder = settings.lastFolderURL;
    onVisibleChanged:
    {
        console.log("lastFolder as string " + settings.lastFolderString);
        console.log("lastFolder as URL " + settings.lastFolderURL);
    }
    onAccepted:
    {
        console.log("Selected folder : " + folder)
        settings.lastFolderString = folder;
        settings.lastFolderURL = folder;
    }
}

Settings {
    id: settings
    property string lastFolderString ;
    property url lastFolderURL;
}
}
```

Comment: Executing the dialog from the C++ side is probably an option, though a pretty ugly one, I hope there is a better way, but thanks.Connecting the remote location as a drive works, but does not solve the crashing problem - people will keep writing to our support that the software crashes when they use network drives (and in my field, people use network drives a lot). I could check if the path is an UNC and don't "remeber" it if it is, but that's taking a bit of convenience from the users.

Comment: But otherwise I agree with your findings - it looks like the FileDialog is doing some kind of conversion/correction of the path during onFolderChanged, but does not take into account UNC paths :(

Comment: Calling QFileDialog from C++ is not necessarily an ugly option, QML is very strong for graphic purpose, but in case of large data processing or specific behavior, it's better to code in C++, Qt say that in the first line of this documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html